firebase giving project id 400 error during get request
i have my firebase.js configured like default, with all the info in my .env.local file, so:
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORA GE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

and when it sends a GET request, then i get this error which chatGPT said is an issue with project_id being undefined, which is correct because when i replace the process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID with its actual string, this error goes away:
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=TwlohVkNMaMBKtkQa_tHlTmP4U4DxfZUMUC8Zi-kopw&VER=8&database=projects%2Fundefined%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=54DbXJWEohNIpyoQqoZ9Jg&AID=0&CI=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=offsjugczyi5&t=1 net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)
useInventory.js:23 
[2024-08-05T07:06:04.050Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.12.4): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x4184a7dd transport errored: 
jd {type: 'c', target: Y, g: Y, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1}

i had a similar 400 issue using the openAI api key, so i routed it to the backend. i thought that doing that for this would work too, so i made an app/api/firebase/getInventory/route.js and just copy-pasted the code i initially had in my app/page.js:
import { firestore } from "@/firebase";
import { getDocs, query, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  const snapshot = query(collection(firestore, "inventory"));
  const docs = await getDocs(snapshot);
  const inventoryList = [];
  docs.forEach((doc) => {
    inventoryList.push({
      name: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    });
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ inventory: inventoryList });
}


does anyone how to fix it? or are the firebase keys all client-side keys anyways and it's basically 'useless' for me to be routing all my get/post requests to the backend?

two things. The first being that NEXT_PUBLIC project require the NEXT prefix for env variables. The second being that when using ENV variable an assert should be used to validate that a value exists or simply cast as string and remove undefined ex: String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY).replace("undefined", "") by doing this it can still throw but, I believe that app still runs. Resource: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

@TheoNeUpKID next projects don't require the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix for env variables. that only exposes your API to the client side, and sometimes, you don't want that because your API is private information. Also, like I mentioned about, my issue is specifically with the project_id key, not any of the other ones

If you don't want to expose any sort of secrets , you need to use the admin SDK. Create a server that handles auth etc using thee admin SDK, all requests will go to the admin SDK enabled server and avoid putting any secrets on the client side.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin
